# How to found item in sql Array laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to find an item by id, but my column is a comma separated string(primaryCategory in below screenshot). I want to get this field in my result when query by any string (i.e. by 50,20,41 etc).

I know there could be options like whereIn, whereHas etc. but not able to find correct syntax. Please help me with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using comma separated string is bad practice for that task, better to create a new table.
But for your structure this way with func `FIND_IN_SET` is suitable:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

```
$categories = [1,2,3];

$queryParts = [];
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $queryParts[] = 'FIND_IN_SET("' . $category . '", `primaryCategory`)';
}

$query = implode(' OR ', $queryParts);

$list = Model::whereRaw($query)->get();
```

**UPD**
Righ solution

Use *ToMany relation:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

You have to create a new table: `model_categories` and put there `model_id` and `category_id`. Every model can have several categories and vise versa, and then you can use the standard laravel `whereHas` function to find models with special categories.

Comment: It worked for me. But could you please explain the correct way as well. As fas as I understood, you are asking to save primaryCategory in different table and then check for each id. With me challenge it my primaryCategory list could be n in length, for 1000 of item it will go to primaryTable and then will check for its parent.